# My Ebony ores haven't respawned, how come?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to mine the Ebony ore in Gloombound mine but, the ore hasn't respawned and I have waited two months.

Answer (score 3):

The respawn timer for a cell gets reset whenever you visit it, you need to wait 10 (or 30, in case of cleared locations) days without visiting a location for it to respawn. Additionally, you may need to leave and reenter a location for respawned ore veins to become interactable.